# Creating a .bash file to test for loop

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to loop through all files located in a directory ending in .txt and rename them (replacing beginning with end). However I would like to take the output from this for loop and pipe it to a bash file so that I can check the file and make sure what I have written does what I want it to, then I can just execute the .bash file if what I see fits the task. I've tried

```
for file in *.txt ; do mv $file ${file//beginning/end} ; done | rename.bash
```

however this renamed the file and created an empty rename.bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `echo` before `mv`. This will print the command instead of executing it.

As well:

- [Quote variables to avoid word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046) on spaces in the filenames. In this case you'll need to put quotes in quotes since you're outputting to a script.
- I've never seen a `.bash` extension in use, so I'd prefer `.sh` instead for the output script.
- You can't pipe directly to a file. Use output redirection `>` instead. If you need to use a pipe, use `tee`.

In sum:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "mv '$file' '${file//beginning/end}'"
done > rename.sh
```

Comment: Why not `.bash`? I name all my bash scripts this way, I think it’s a good practice to have the interpreter as the script file extension, this way you see what’s a `sh` script and what’s a `bash` one without opening the file.

Comment: @dessert Because `.sh` scripts are typical for Bourne-shell scripts in general and extensions are generally a preference of the user/author :) There exit several `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` scripts on Ubuntu which don't use any extension at all either. A good example of that is `on_ac_power`

Comment: Also generally a user shouldn't need to know if it's a bash script or not.  As author you already know, so there's no point.

Comment: @dessert Good point! A quick Google found points [for .bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299621/117037) and [for .sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23160135/4518341) (by convention). I guess ultimately it's personal preference. Personally I don't use it cause Gedit doesn't automatically syntax-highlight a .bash file unless it has a shebang. I might have also been thinking of the Python extension debate, where `.py3` files won't even be recognized as modules.

Answer (score 3):

Because `mv` doesn't output anything, and you can't pipe into a file.

What you *can* do is create a bash script using redirector:

```
for file in *.txt
 do
 echo "mv $file $(some command to manipulate the text)" >> script.bash
done
```

This will append the command to the file.